# wkhtmltopdf integrated with php doesn't work on Centos (access deny)

Tags: php, centos, wkhtmltopdf

I installed wkhtmltopdf on my Centos server.
Everything works fine in the shell. If I try to send the command in the shell:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.it /var/www/html/test_report.pdf
```

or simply

```
wkhtmltopdf ... /var/www/html/test_report.pdf
```

everything goes well, but the same is not working if i use the exec command in a php script:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.it /var/www/html/test_report.pdf");
```

I changed the `chmod` of the html folder in 0777, but in the access.log I have the following response:

> [08/Oct/2012:17:11:18 +0200] "GET test_report.php HTTP/1.1"
>   200 311 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/15.0.1"

The same script works fine on a windows 2003 server.

Is there a way to get around this error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely SELinux is blocking it, I had the same issue once.

Don't disable SELinux (that's just a bad idea/the lazy man's way to "fix" it), but use the `audit2allow` tool instead to figure out what context/SELinux booleans need to be altered.

See http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01 for more details.

Comment: do you think that could be a good idea to disable the SELinux and make  a test before try to "fix" it?

Comment: @Michi you can always temporarily disable it to be sure it's SELinux blocking the pdf creation. Just run `setenforce 0`, try again and see if it works. Re-enable it with `setenforce 1` (I would highly recommend to keep it enabled, just with the proper rules).

Comment: Your solution seems right! i disabled the SELinux and now i'm able to create the pdf file using wkhtmltopdf+php.
Now the problem is: what should i change in the SELinux in order to keep it working with the "right" rule? (consider that i'm totally rookie with Linux!)

Comment: @Michi Good to hear. In order to find the "villain" check the link I posted earlier. Use `audit2allow` to find out what needs to be done. I don't think audit2allow comes with a CentOS6 install by default, so you'll probably need to install it with yum. I think it's a tool of another package, so try `yum provides */audit2allow` to see what package it's part of and install that. Then follow the instructions from the link above.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! i've installed audit2allow and i have the following response with audit2allow -a:

#============= httpd_sys_script_t ==============
allow httpd_sys_script_t self:process execmem;


#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t postgresql_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow httpd_t self:process execmem;
allow httpd_t tmp_t:sock_file write;

#============= xdm_t ==============
allow xdm_t admin_home_t:dir read;

To tell you the truth.. i don't have any idea to what to activate/deactivate for enabling the file-creation with php.

Comment: @Michi I think you'd best ask the guys over at http://serverfault.com/ in a seperate question how to apply those settings exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was SELinux (as @Oldskool mentioned his answer). In `exec`output there was only information `PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE failed.`

To resolve the problem I ran:

`setsebool httpd_execmem on`

I found this solution at [groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wkhtmltopdf-general/dJ2QdC1LVKc/NkL5lU4sEicJ)

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. But is there any drawbacks on using this solution compared to the audit2allow above?